# Access custom attributes via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I need to access to the custom attribute or data of my link but I can't. My code is simple yet in repeater. I don't know if this is causing a problem. Here is the code:

```
 <a class="showAllComm" data-userid='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "USER_ID")%>' href="#sa">Show all comments</a>
```

Here is my click event:

```
$('.showAllComm').click(function(index, element) {
            var commId = $(element).data("userid");
 })
```

commId is undefined but I can see it in the source code that it has value of 1.

how can I access to the userId?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference the element with `this` instead of the second parameter:

```
var commId = $(this).data("userid");
```

---

The arguments passed to an event handler are not the `index` and `element` as you'd have in `.each()`.

By default, you just get a single `event` argument passed.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jjbwd/

```
$('.showAllComm').click(function( event ) {

    alert( event.type ) // click

    var commId = $(this).data("userid");
});
```

Comment: thank you but I wonder.. what is the reason for not being able to access with element?

Comment: @Pabuc because there _is_ no second parameter to the callback, the only parameter is a jQuery event object.

Comment: In these cases there's no need to create the jQuery object, a simpler `$.data(this, "userid")` would be more efficient...as it just does a `this[$.expando]` call, rather than a full jQuery() call/init.

Comment: @Pabuc: Because jQuery doesn't pass a second argument by default.

Comment: @Nick: Are you sure that works to initially access `data-` attributes that are not yet in `jQuery.cache`? It doesn't seem that way in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hP3x8/).

Comment: @patrick - ah you're right...there's been a regression there in core

Answer (score 1):

The `data` method is not a shortcut for the `attr` method.  It takes an element and an attribute, [per the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Just use `attr("data-userid")`

Comment: Well I'll be.  Maybe if I'd been using this all along I wouldn't have gotten lazy about using a `data` prefix on all my data attributes.